# I have a error in makefile while running xv6 in ubuntu

Tags: xv6

i have cloned the xv6-public repository in ubuntu virtual box and i have used the commands

```
$sudo apt-get install qemu
$git clone https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public.git
$cd xv6-public
$make
$make qemu-nox
```

when i run make qemu-nox i am getting error like below

```
***
*** Error: Couldn't find a working QEMU executable.
*** Is the directory containing the qemu binary in your PATH
*** or have you tried setting the QEMU variable in Makefile?
***
nographic -drive file=fs.img,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -drive file=xv6.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -smp 2 -m 512 
make: nographic: Command not found
make: [Makefile:231: qemu-nox] Error 127 (ignored)
```

can anyone give any solution for this

Comment: Hi
Do you have `qemu` installed on you system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've learned this solution from somebody named Amrollahi.
Try these steps, if your current step works, don't try the rest of it.

#### one:

```
make clean
```

---

```
make
```

---

```
make qemu
```

#### two:

```
sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
```

*then repeat step one.*

#### three:

try this [link](https://medium.com/@sasini.dissanayake/add-a-user-program-in-xv6-e981c0c9bb27#:%7E:text=In%20case%20if%20you%20get,to%20QEMUOPTS%20line%20in%20Makefile).

#### four:

you can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507764/error-couldnt-find-a-working-qemu-executable).